# C# LINQ: DbFunctions.TruncateTime throw error This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

here is my code.

```
    List<NPSEntity> Data = null; ;
    using (var db = new NPSDbContext())
    {
        Data = (from n in db.NPSDatas
                    orderby n.AddDate, n.CountryCode
                    where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(n.NPSDate) >= StartDate.Date && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(n.NPSDate) <= EndDate
                    select n).ToList();
    }

    NPSData = Data.Select(n => new NPSEntity
    {
        NPSDate = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(n.NPSDate),
        NPSAmount = n.NPSAmount,
        AddDate = n.AddDate,
        ModDate = n.ModDate,
        UserID = n.UserID,
        CountryCode = n.CountryCode
    }).ToList();

    if (NPSData!=null)
    {
        CountryCodes = NPSData.Select(e => e.CountryCode).Distinct();
        CountryCount = CountryCodes.Count();
    }
```

this line throwing error `NPSDate = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(n.NPSDate),` **This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities**

my objective is to remove time portion from **NPSDate**  `NPSDate = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(n.NPSDate)` that is why i used `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` function.

tell me how could i fix this problem or tell me how could i remove time portion from NPSDate when fetching data from db. my NPSDate property look like `public DateTime? NPSDate { get; set; }` that is why i can not use `NPSDate.Date`

please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error is self explanatory enough, that you cannot use `DbFunctions` in any other context, the context should only be **Linq to Entities** and when you call `ToList()` on an `IQueryable<T>`, the query gets executed and results are brought in memory, you would need to use `Date` property of `DateTime` if truncating the time is needed here like:

```
NPSData = Data.Select(n => new NPSEntity
{
    NPSDate = n.NPSDate.Date,
```

Comment: i can not use `n.n.NPSDate.Date.Date` because my n.NPSDate property is nullable type `public DateTime? NPSDate { get; set; }` so i can not use Date property.

Comment: then: `n.NPSDate.Value.Date`, more better is to check for null : `n.NPSDate.HasValue ? n.NPSDate.Value.Date ? null `